# Query File Version using powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

I have a code that let me query one file version at the time.How can I query all file version inside of this registry key or if I just want to query specific files including firefox, chrome, etc.?

```
(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\communicator.exe').'(Default)' | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo | Select FileDescription,ProductVersion
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing a literal path you should run `Get-ChildItem` on the "folder" the registry keys are contained in you are interested in. The result of this you pipe to your piece of code ...  like this:

```
$Path =  'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths'

Get-ChildItem -Path $Path | 
ForEach-Object {
    Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty '(default)' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-Item -Path $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Select-Object FullName -ExpandProperty VersionInfo
    }
} |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Ok, I just need the fileversion, productversion and installdate

Comment: The code I posted is a suggestion. Of course you are allowed to adapt it to your needs as you like. As far as I know there is no attribute "installdate" in the file system or in the registry path you specified in your question. You will have to figure out where this infromation is stored and extract it accordingly. ;-)